# Are there ways to listen for inserts to a specific database table?

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have two applications. One use the node.js, the second use php.

I'm looking for a way to listen changes to a `notifications` table that a node.js makes.

Here's the pseudocode:

```
$database->whenInsertToTable('notifications', function() {
     // Do something with new notifications...
});
```

At the moment, the only implementation option I see is creating a task that will, for example, check the notification table every minute, but there is a drawback. If the insert was made immediately after the last check, then we will get a 59 second delay.

It seems to me that checking the table every second is also not the best solution, because this is a select every second. I'm trying to find a ready-made solution/library that would listen to database events.

Comment: Depends what you want to do. You could add a database trigger to do something at the data level. Alternatively, some DBMS provide ways to subscribe to their transaction logs

Comment: @Phil Can I subscribe to logs, for example via websocket?

Comment: or either you can act at node level using a callback of the insert query

Comment: What database are you using? What options does it offer?

Comment: @deceze Im using postgresql.

Comment: You could use listen/notify combined with a database trigger - but that has no guarantee that you will never lose a notification

Comment: Have a look at [Debezium](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.9/). It does exactly what you want via Apache Kafka as a message broker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach would be to use a message broker like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/). node.js would insert into the database and then publish an event on Rabbit. PHP will listen to this event and trigger whatever logic you want to attach this event.

Or you could call an API in you PHP application from node.js after the insert. This would probably be more lightweight if this is only for a smaller application.